# .NET Core output directory does not include platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am  working on a .NET Core Project on Visual Studio 2015.

When I Build my project (WebApi project) I see the output being built to `bin\Debug\net461`

but when i try Debug my program, it seems that MSVS2015 expects running my assembly from `bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64`.
**Edit Error message :**
`The Debug executable 'd:\...\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\AddYoursWebApi.exe' debug profile does not exist.`

I find it hard figuring how to either Tell VS to run without the platform dir(Win7-x64),
or either, build the output to include the platform dir.

Please help.

Comment: What does Visual Studio do or tell you that makes you believe that VS expects the running assembly to be at that location?

Comment: You can close project and edit the .proj/.cproj file to correct any errors.  They are text files.

Comment: @jdweng you mean `.xproj` files,
but i dont see either the Debug Command nor the full output dir. all i see there is `<OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">.\bin\</OutputPath>`

Comment: @MichaelGunter Edited the question quoting the error message

Comment: Whether the AddYoursWebApi.exe exist in the path "bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64"? If not, you should add the runtime in the peoject.json file, like:  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {}
  },